# String Manipulation in Verilog

Tags: string, verilog, system-verilog

I need to perform basic operations on strings like concatenation,replacement and comparison in my Verilog simulation. How could it be possible? Is there any built-in support?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have access to a modern simulator which supports SystemVerilog syntax, there is a `string` data type.  Strings can be concatenated and compared.  Refer to the IEEE Std (1800-2009).

Answer (score 5):

There is no string datatype in Verilog however verilog does support string literals and using them as byte vectors. This is the example from the spec:

```
module string_test;
reg [8*14:1] stringvar;
initial begin
  stringvar = "Hello world";
  $display ("%s is stored as %h", stringvar,stringvar);
  stringvar = {stringvar,"!!!"};
  $display ("%s is stored as %h", stringvar,stringvar);
  end
endmodule
```

Since strings use the reg datatype you can use the normal operators to manipulate them, keeping in mind each character uses 8 bits.

> 5.2.3.1 String operations
>
> The common string operations copy, concatenate, and compare are supported by Verilog HDL operators. Copy
>   is provided by simple assignment. Concatenation is provided by the
>   concatenation operator. Comparison is provided by the equality
>   operators. When manipulating string values in vector regs, the regs
>   should be at least 8*n bits (where n is the number of ASCII
>   characters) in order to preserve the 8-bit ASCII code.

You'll have to write some tasks or functions if you need operations like searching.

Answer (score 0):

sjtaheri,

Reviving a dead thread, but I see this question come up, and there is a newer solution for it.

svlib is a free, open-source library of utility functions for SystemVerilog. It includes file and string manipulation functions, full regular expression search/replace, easy reading and writing of configuration files, access to environment variables and wall-clock time, and much more. This project was presented at DVCon 2014.

http://www.verilab.com/resources/svlib/